# Is it feasible to create an OS specifically for games console emulation?

Tags: operating-system, emulation

As currently emulators are run inside an existing OS, that OS is not 100% optimised to give as much of its resources as possible to the emulator.

Would it be possible to create or modify an OS that you could boot into and straight away have options to load roms etc without spending system resources on anything other than necessary for emulation. (Perhaps custom Linux distro?)

Comment: So, basically, you want to turn the computer into a semi-dedicated console?

Comment: Pretty much, or have that OS installed side by side.

Comment: It'd definitely be possible; a modern console is pretty much just a computer with an OS dedicated to running games.  Whether it's useful outside of an actual console is a whole other question, the answer to which depends on whether you really need to dedicate that much to the emulator resourcewise.  For all but the latest consoles, you probably don't.

Comment: So then let's say that resources are not an issue, but time is - what would be a good way to boot into some kind of emulation software as quickly as possible?

Comment: Today's desktops and most laptops are more than powerful enough to run any current game system under emulation. An OS like Linux or Windows would already have the drivers making an emulator much easier to write. Also if you could write emulators for the wii, playstation 3 and xbox, you will be able to run them all under one OS and not require reboots to switch between them. There really isn't a good reason to write a complete OS.

Comment: Okay, so would it be possible under Linux for a seamless emulation menu lets say as the first thing you see upon boot? Just as a kind of wrapper that makes it look as if you have booted straight into an emulator and so that you can just turn it on and select a ROM?

Comment: Yes, if you use a graphical boot, you can configure what it displays and then boot into whatever program you want. It doesn't have to a display manager or console.